# Laravel | Override default DB::connection only once inside scope

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, pdo, query-builder

I have multiple MySQL connections to different databases in my Laravel application. I understand that I cannot override the default connection with `DB::connection` , but I am wondering if there is a way to override this only once within a given scope of a function.

For example I am currently:

```php
DB::connection('mysql2')->table('users')->select ...
DB::connection('mysql2')->table('orders')->insert ...
...
...
```

But I wish to:

```php
DB::connection('mysql2'); // override connection once in this scope
DB::table('users')->select ...
DB::table('orders')->insert ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
$conn = DB::connection('mysql2')
$conn->table('users')->select ...
$conn->table('orders')->insert ...
```